# Math round from JSON number

Tags: javascript, php, json, math, rounding

I have this code, perhaps not correct:

```
<?php echo round(" + json.list[0].number + ");?> // number is 25.54864869
```

I want round number to 25 but this code is wrong. How can I do?

---

Now I post full code because I haven't solved

```
<script language='javascript'>
    $(document).ready(init);

    function init() {
        $.getJSON("file.json").done(onSuccess).fail(onError);
    }

    function onSuccess(json) {
        console.log(json);
        $("#box").html("<table style='border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid #ddddcc;color:#000000;width:100%;text-aling:center;'>" +
        "<tr><td style='width:25%;'> </td><td>" + json.list[0].dt_txt +  "</td><td>" etc etc
```

Comment: Can you use JS.....?

Comment: show how does `json` object looks like?

Comment: You're trying to round a String... Remove the quotes and the + signs. `<?php echo round(json.list[0].number);?> //26`

Comment: quotes are unnecessary

Comment: Yes, I use also javascript

Comment: If remove string I have alike syntax error. Now I post full code: <script language='javascript'>
        $(document).ready(init);

        function init() {
            $.getJSON("/file.json").done(onSuccess).fail(onError);
        }

        function onSuccess(json) {
            console.log(json);
            $("#box").html("<table style='border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid #ddddcc;color:#000000;width:100%;text-aling:center;'>" +
            "<tr><td style='width:25%;'> </td><td>" + json.list[0].number +  "</td><td>" + json.list[1].number "</td><td>" ecc...

Answer (score 0):

Why not ?

```
$number = 25.54864869;
echo floor($number); // 25
```

Answer (score 0):

With only javascript you can do:

```
Math.floor(25.54864869) //25
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work with JavaScript

```
Math.floor(25.54864869) // 25
```